# How can I link my directive to html from the typescript class?

Tags: angularjs-directive, typescript, angular-directive

I am working on a angular directive POC. Here I have an HTML page and a controller class. I have method in my typescript class that returns a directive. Also I have a placeholder for this directive in the HTML page. How can I link these two.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>    
    <script data-main="main" src="scripts/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body  ng-controller="TypeScriptController as TSCtrl">
    <helloworld> </helloworld>
</body>
</html>
```

/////controller class

```
export class TypeScriptController {

name: string;
place: string;
output: string;
text: string;
helloworld: ng.IDirective;
protected ngModule: ng.IModule = null;

constructor() {
    this.name = "Obama";
    this.place = "America";
    this.text = "welcome";
    this.helloworld = this.getCustomDirective();
    //how can link this helloworld directive to the html
}

getCustomDirective(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: [TypeScriptController],
        controllerAs: "TSCtrl",
        //templateUrl: "first.html"
        template: '<h1>{{TSCtrl.place}}</h1>'
    };
}
}

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    var main: TypeScriptController = new TypeScriptController();
});
```

How can I link the helloworld directive the html. I don't have a "ng-app" name  to do something like..

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', myDirective);

I want to register the directive from inside the class not outside it..I want to create module or something similar inside the class and then use it to register the directive.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I link these two.

Not without creating an `angular.module`. Controllers are looked up from `window` but directive's are not. Also if you don't have an `ng-app` (or bootstrap) then Angular will not do *directive tag* -> *directive* transform for that section of html.

Comment: Thanks basarat.. Can I create an angular.module without having an "ng-app".  Otherwise How can I use bootstrap to achieve this?.. My ultimate aim is to use pluggable components in html. I want to create placeholders inside the html and inject directives or similar components to these placeholders from my typescript class. Not from outside class...Thank you in advance..